# What is the correct usage of the tilde symbol with negative numbers?

Tags: formality, mathematics, science

The tilde symbol (**~**) is used in academic texts in place of *about* or *approximately*.

Generally, it is placed immediately before the number (eg. AUD ~2.4 million), which works for positive numbers, where the positive symbol is not shown. However, when dealing with a negative number, the negative symbol is shown (eg. -3.7).

If this were an approximate value, would the tilde be placed before or after the negative symbol (~-3.7) or -~3.7)?

Comment: The number is literally "approximately minus three". The number is literally *not* "minus approximately three". That is not how you say it, so I don't understand why that's what you'd want to write.

Comment: This is a question of mathematical conventions, not English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English.

Comment: @RegDwigнt What exactly is wrong with "minus approximately three"?

Comment: @michael.hor257k there is nothing wrong with it at all. That is not my point, and you know it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I know nothing of the kind.

Comment: @michael.hor257k good thing I mentioned it, then. So you do know it now.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I have no patience for this. You said: *The number is literally not "minus approximately three". That is not how you say it*. I disagree. If you don't want to give reasons for your statement, don't. But please refrain from these stupid games.

Comment: I would say either *approximately minus three* or *minus approximately three* depending on the order of the symbols. While there is likely a subtle semantic difference, it's not meaningful enough to make a practical difference. (And I wouldn't claim that either order is any more *correct*.) In *English writing* I would likely dispense with the tilde in order to prevent ambiguity between the two symbols (and use *about* or *approximately* instead). I don't know what the mathematical convention is for denoting the expression (but answering that is off topic here).

Comment: ~(-3).In my experience very few people know what ~x means,

Comment: The tilde DOES NOT MEAN THAT in published works! The symbol you want is a wavy equal sign  ≈, U+2248 "Almost equal to". The single tilde means either "of the same order of magnitude", or "approaches as an asymptote", depending on context. See p25 of [API Style Guide](http://web.mit.edu/me-ugoffice/communication/aip_style_4thed.pdf), section 5. Now, would you write =-5 or -=5?

Answer (score -1):

The [article on tildes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#As_a_unary_operator) states

> A tilde in front of a single quantity can mean "approximately", "about" or "of the same order of magnitude as."

This I would interpret as being ~(-10), with -10 being the "single quantity".